# Mysql Workbench doesn't start on Fedora 20

Tags: mysql-workbench, fedora20

MySQL Workbench doesn't start on Fedora 20.

I don't understand the problem.

I tried to remove and reinstall it without a results.

Comment: Can't you use `mysql`  on the command line... ?

Comment: @ Basile Starynkevitch yes

Comment: Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 2
Server version: 5.5.43-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

Comment: Your question is merely don't show what is the approach to install the MySQL Workbench!
Try seeing the MySQL Workbench logs or please search over internet and try them by yourself first!

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71646

Comment: I found only this. I used yum to install and remove and in the log doesn't write nothing. bad things.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which MySQL Workbench version you tried, so I assume it was the latest one (6.3.4 at the time being). This version only supports Fedora 21 and 22. Additionally, MySQL Workbench has only been tested with MySQL servers. There's no testing, bug fixing etc. for other servers.

So, I recommend that you split your problems into 2: first get MySQL Workbench running at all. You can try that even on Fedora 20, but don't hold your breath for it to work - better upgrade to a more recent OS. Once this is solved you can start trying to do your work. Best would be to use MySQL, as there is no advantage by using MariaDB over MySQL, but you have less troubles.

Comment: Sebastion, please accept my answer if it helped you (see the checkmark on the left side of the answer).